# How can i make my Arabic to roman algorithm better?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I've made an arabic to roman numerals converter in python all the way by myself (havent googled a single example)

```
def arabic_to_roman(num: int) -> str:
    roman_dict = {1000: 'M', 500: 'D', 100: 'C', 50: 'L', 10: 'X', 5: 'V', 1: 'I'}
    roman_num = ''
    exp_list = []
    chars = list(roman_dict.values())
    if num > 3999:
        return num

    else:
        for key in roman_dict.keys():
            exp = num // key
            num -= key * (num // key)
            exp_list.append(exp)

        pattern = [[chars[i], exp_list[i]] for i in range(len(chars))]
        print(pattern)

        # algorithm turning IIII into IV, VIIII into IX etc 

        for i in range(len(pattern)):
            for j in range(i - 2, i - 1):
                if pattern[j][1] > 3:
                    if pattern[j - 1][1] == 0:
                        pattern[j][1] = 1
                        pattern[j][0] = pattern[j][0] + pattern[j - 1][0]
                    else:
                        pattern[j][1] = 1
                        pattern[j - 1][1] = 0
                        pattern[j][0] = pattern[j][0] + pattern[j - 2][0]

        print(pattern)
    
        #concatenation the roman num from pattern
        for i in range(len(pattern)):
            roman_num += pattern[i][0][:2] * pattern[i][1]

        return roman_num
```

i dont like the parth where i use slicing in concatenation because my IIII -> IV algorithm creates extra characters in certain cases like XCD instead of XC or XCM instead of XC. How can i change the IIII -> IV part to make it work without using the slicing?

```
import random, time
start_time = time.time()

def my_test():

    my_list = [random.randint(1, 3999) for _ in range(1000000)]
    my_romanlist = [arabic_to_roman(i) for i in my_list]
    print(my_list[1], my_romanlist[1])
   
my_test()

print(f"{time.time() - start_time} seconds")
```

And here is my test, it takes about 16 seconds on my PC. is it good? how can i optimize the arabic_to_roman function to make it work faster?

Thanks in advance

okay now i've made a `roman_dict = {1000: 'M', 900: 'CM', 500: 'D', 400: 'CD', 100: 'C', 90: 'XC', 50: 'L', 40: 'XL', 10: 'X', 9: 'IX', 5: 'V', 4: 'IV', 1: 'I'}`

instead of older one and commented IIII-> IV part, but the test still takes approx the same amount of time. But the previous questions are still actual:)

Comment: If this is running code, this might be better suited for Code Review Stack Exchange. First thing that springs to mind is the `num > 3999` case, which is not consistent with the type hints.

Comment: thats because original roman numerals are from 1 to 3999, and i dont know how to use 5000 character, 10000 character etc its like V or X with _ on the top but i think we can extend the dictionary with new key\value pairs and that would work also for 1 to 3999999 roman numerals

Comment: @PRD Then instead of returning the `num` that you input in that case, return a string. Perhaps `str(num)`.

Comment: @BenGrossmann better to return None. str(num) is not likely to be a Roman numeral

Comment: @JCaesar `None` is also not consistent with the type hint. Perhaps the empty string `''` is a better choice. I went with `str(num)` because this is closest to what OP seemed to have in mind

Comment: @BenGrossmann Indeed, empty string might be better. Should also test for num > 0

Comment: I don't think that your testing procedure is very accurate, as it times slow things such as prints rather than the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Non-recursive (not that that's necessarily a bad thing) version that runs in <1.1s on my machine:

```
control = [
    (1000, 'M'),
    (900, 'CM'),
    (500, 'D'),
    (400, 'CD'),
    (100, 'C'),
    (90, 'XC'),
    (50, 'L'),
    (40, 'XL'),
    (10, 'X'),
    (9, 'IX'),
    (5, 'V'),
    (4, 'IV'),
    (1, 'I')
]


def int_to_roman(num):
    roman_num = []
    for x, c in control:
        if (r := num // x):
            roman_num.append(f'{c*r}')
            if (num := num - r * x) == 0:
                break
    return ''.join(roman_num)

import time
import random
rnums = [random.randint(1, 3_999) for _ in range(1_000_000)]
start = time.perf_counter()
R = [int_to_roman(rnum) for rnum in rnums]
end = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Duration={end-start:.4f}s')
```

**Output:**

```
Duration=1.0627s
```

Comment: i need to try to write your cycle without := to figure out how it works exactly
thx

Comment: Or you could upgrade your Python to 3.8+ and/or review https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the last part of your question: "how can I optimize the arabic_to_roman function to make it work faster?" Here's an alternative method that I made, which seems to work fairly quickly.

```
roman_dict = {1000:'M',900:'CM',500:'D',400:'CD',
                  100:'C',90:'XC',50:'L',40:'XL',
                  10:'X',9:'IX',5:'V',4:'CV',1:'I'}
vals = list(roman_dict)

def arabic_to_roman(num:int)->str:
    if num == 0:
        return ''
    for v in vals:
        if num >= v:
            return roman_dict[v] + arabic_to_roman(num-v)
```

Running your test, I found that this method is about 3X faster than the method you've presented.

Comment: I like the fact that your code is more succinct than my offering. Sadly, it takes >3 times longer to run

Comment: @JCaesar Interesting, I guess recursion slows things down a bit. I also wonder what effect cycling through tuples as as opposed to using the dictionary as I have. Then again, I can't really expect to do better than a Roman with Roman numerals

Comment: @JCaesar I've sped things up a bit by using a global variable to avoid repeated sorting

Comment: Not wishing to seem too pedantic but the sort is unnecessary anyway as the keys are already descending

Comment: @JCaesar Interesting, I was under the impression that making a dictionary into a list scrambles the key into an apparently random order. Perhaps that's a difference between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: That is indeed a difference. The keys are ordered according to how they were inserted/created. They are not sorted. But your declaration was explicitly sorted so... nothing to be done